# Build an extensible and modular Rails application with pluggable modules, configuration and views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, architecture

I want to create an application with a basic structure: a bunch of controllers, models, views, locales, configs, etc. The application lives into a specific path of my server (call it: PATH1).

I want other collegues to be able to extend/override those files without modifying the original ones. They may want to customize views or add fields to existing models or, even, add methods to existing controllers.
And they should work and put their files within a dedicated directory into the same server (call it: PATH2)

The main point is that they cannot access the original codebase, but only extend it.

The final application runs as usual, by loading all files from PATH1 and PATH2.
I've read about Rails Engines, and I'm wondering if I can achieve this result with them.

Anyone have experience with such infrastructure?

Thanks a lot ;)

Comment: I can only contribute by suggesting the use of an API, but other than that, I'd need to look at how to do that! May I ask why you're looking to structure it this way?

Comment: There're lots of employees (frontend devs, designers, etc) that cannot read/copy the underlying framework of the application they work with. Their goal is to create multiple Rails applications (running for different clients) that have different charateristics (they create custom views, add fields, etc). A similar situation of the RefineryCMS where you can create custom extensions.

Comment: Why don't you make a gem?

Comment: The reason is those people have little or no experience with Rails and I want them to follow rigid guidelines and create few files (mainly views), not an entire Rails skeleton. The process I'd like to use is: I create an app's skeleton for every person, configure each one to be overriden by user's files, the user works on its directory, the application runs on the web! :) have you any idea?

Comment: Maybe Rails isn't the right tool for this job - it sounds like you'd be better creating a framework, which you'd be able to allow people to use (like Wordpress)

Comment: Would it be possible If I create the skeleton of the user's APP that uses the GEM of my Application. Then I enable users to access (read and write) only the app/views, app/models directories of that application. In this case they'll not see any of my original files and still working with their views and models. Right?

Answer (score 0):

I would read or watch this episode on railscasts:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/277-mountable-engines

It's a free episode and should point you into the right direction. If this is not what you want/need you would have to create a database driven approach where people can add a path name and then add their code via web based editor which gets stored in the database and executed upon load. I promise you with this approach that you are in for security trouble if you or the other devs don't know exactly what they are doing.

Another option would be to use something like refinery which is an expandable CMS system and people can cause less damage:)